# How to properly compute noise power spectral density?

Tags: sampling, noise-spectral-density, power-spectral-density, johnsonnyquist

I am confused about two different definitions of *Power Spectral Density (PSD)* that I have seen online.
The first comes from the [National Instruments LabVIEW documentation](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labwindows-cvi/page/advancedanalysisconcepts/lvac_noise_level_and_power_spectral_density.html) (1):

$$
PSD = \frac{PS}{\Delta f*W}
$$
where *W* is the *Noise Power Bandwidth of the Window*, i.e., 1.5 for a Hanning window (the LabVIEW Power Spectrum / PSD vi uses Welch's method to derive the PSD.) [This article from Siemens](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/article/what-is-a-power-spectral-density-psd#:%7E:text=A%20Power%20Spectral%20Density%20(PSD)%20is%20the%20measure%20of%20signal%27s,amplitude%20units%20of%20g2%2FHz.) also derives the *PSD* by dividing by the frequency resolution.

The second (2) comes from Wikipedia regarding [thermal noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) (which is eventually what I would like to measure):
$$
\bar{v}_n^2 =4k_BTR\times BW
$$
where *BW* is the bandwidth of my measurement, i.e., the noise power bandwidth of my measurement apparatus. This definition is also explained in this [documentation by Zurich instruments](https://www.zhinst.com/americas/en/blogs/noise-spectral-density-measured-lock-amplifiers).

I am using a waveform digitizer with a sampling rate of 20 MSamples/s that has a built-in 3rd-order 10 MHz butterworth low-pass filter to prevent aliasing. My record length is 16384 samples.

Using (1),
$$
\frac{PS}{PSD} = \frac{20\hspace{0.1cm}MSamp/s}{16384\times1.5} = 1.831 \hspace{0.1cm}kHz.
$$

Using (2),
$$
\frac{PS}{PSD} = 10\hspace{0.1cm}MHz\times1.0472 = 10.472\hspace{0.1cm}MHz
$$
where 1.0472 is the equivalent noise bandwidth parameter of the butterworth filter.

Clearly, these methods are not equivalent. I think it has something to do with the fact that I am digitizing an analog signal rather than calculating the PSD of a continuous signal. Or, maybe it is different when specifically measuring noise (i.e., Johnson-Nyquist thermal noise)? However, I am having a lot of trouble finding any clear literature on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!